# .NET DataTable is mangling date field from an Excel file

Tags: c#, .net, excel, oledb, etl

I'm writing a lot of Extract Transform Load code right now for work. To make it easier to read in data from user-generated Excel spreadsheets from within SSIS, I've written a little library that reads the column header layout from an Excel file and dumps the data into a table in a MS SQL database that has the same schema as the Excel file. It's working great so far, but I'm having a couple of odd hiccups.

(Yes, I know that SSIS supports stuff like this natively. There are technical reasons for the approach I've chosen, and explaining them would go beyond the scope of this post.)

The problem is that with some input files, any columns with date information get mangled. For instance, when I perform the import, the date string `12/09/2013` gets mangled into `41617`; `Dec 9, 2013 9:19:58 AM` becomes `41617.388866`. I've checking to see if it's trying to treat `12/09/2013` as a mathematical equation, but `(12/09)/2013 = 6.62361`. Also, I've checked the cell formatting on this spreadsheet as well as a few others that are importing date fields without errors, and it's the same everywhere - Custom, mm/dd/yyyy.

The biggest problem here is that, due to the nature of the process I've written, everything hinges on my not knowing the structure of the file at runtime. I can transform the data on the fly, but I have no idea how to work backwards from `41617` to get to `12/09/2013`.

DateTime.TryParse is also unhelpful:

```
DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParse("41617", out dt);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString());
```

outputs

```
1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
```

Here's a link to a stripped, de-identified copy of the spreadsheet that I'm having trouble with: [View / Download from Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-0ZHwApBp-OT0UxTF9SaG1PZjA/edit?usp=sharing)

I am using an OLE DB connection string to read the data from the Excel (2007) file:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FilePath + ";Extended Properties = \"Excel 12.0 XML; HDR=YES; IMEX=1\";"
```

Using the Interop classes is not an option. They're  not set up on the server, and as a contractor, it's not likely that I'll be able to get IT to set it up.

Then, I'm using a `OleDbCommand()` that just runs `SELECT *` against the Excel sheet, and filling a DataSet with the result.

This has me really stumped, and I would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using

```
DateTime.FromOADate(value)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this - it's a much cleaner solution... but I'm glad that Rik posted his answer, as the background is really interesting!

Comment: Just remember that it'll be off by 1 for dates between 1899-12-31 and 1900-03-01.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit** 
I actually recommend using [Joe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20972515/5409) (which I did not know about before just now). Just remember that it'll be off by 1 for dates between 1899-12-31 and 1900-03-01.
I'm leaving my answer here to supply some background information.

Excel stores dates as the number of days passed starting from Januari 1st 1900 (day 1), except that it treats the year 1900 as a leap year. (due to a bug with Lotus 123, with which they wanted to be compatible) so there's an extra day for dates after Februari 28th 1900.

Our beloved Joel Spolsky wrote [an article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/06/16.html) mentioning this a few years ago.

You can use this method to convert an integer Excel date to a `DateTime`

```
public static DateTime ConvertFromExcelDate(int excelDate)
{
    if (excelDate > 59) excelDate--; // 59 == februari 29
    return (new DateTime(1899,12,31)).AddDays(excelDate); // 19000101 == 1, so 18991231 == 0
}
```

Be sure to clearly document this in your code, because this will certainly raise questions in the future for people unfamiliar with this issue.

Comment: Okay - we're on to something here... my target value is 12/09/2013, but new DateTime(1900, 1, 1).AddDays(41617) returns 12/11/2013 - can I just safely assume that I can subtract 2 from the integer value I'm getting for these columns (1 for the leap day, 1 for the value of Jan 1 itself)?

Comment: See my edit. I you're sure you don't have to handle dates before March 1st 1900 correctly, you just substract 2.

Comment: For the sake of pedantry, after a little experimentation, I've discovered that Excel actually treats 0 as January 0, 1900, which isn't processable by the .NET Framework, so December 31, 1899 is the correct start date. Your function is perfect - thanks so much for your time!